# Can't list result from sql to html table

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to list the data from mysql to a html table using php in main html file. I've been through all of the other questions on here and I'm sure I have mostly the same methods and code as them.

For some reason (which I suspect has something to do with mysql and not the code) the only result is a blank table with one row and five columns. Each time I try to implement the other codes they just seem to print text onto the site.

I'm very confused as I think I've done the right thing. I've even been able to list the data from mysql through php echo so I know it's there and that I can access it. Really would appreciate some help on this. Thank you.

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "daemon", "xampp", "test");
            if (!$connect) {
                die(mysqli_error());
            }
            $results = mysqli_query("SELECT title,url,details,file,submission_date FROM input");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            ?>
                    <td><?php echo $row['title']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['url']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['details']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['file']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['submission_date']?></td>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: have you launched the same query on phpmyadmin or similar?

Comment: check for errors after execute the query.

Comment: I just ran a print view, if that's what you mean and it ran perfectly, as expected.

Comment: @Jens could you explain what you mean by checking for errors, I'm quite new to this so I'm not sure how to go about that

Comment: you should also echo `<tr>` `</tr>` tags

Comment: @Pepo_rasta If I don't have any `<tr>` `</tr>` tags, why would I need to do that?

Comment: You should add` or mysqli_error()` after `$results = mysqli_query("SELECT title,url,details,file,submission_date FROM input")`

Comment: Sorry @Jens could you be more specific, the way I'm trying to do it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I added `if (!mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT title,url,details,file,submission_date FROM input"))
            {
      echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connect));
     }`

Comment: You could try placing the php inside a try/catch block and see what happens then: `try{  --php code-- }catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
}`. Also,  you can `print_r($results)` to check what's returning the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say this code is in your mail html file? And it is printing out onto the screen? Try changing your file to .php not .html! Php code won't run in a .html file, and will likely output your code directly onto the page.

Comment: Sorry I should explain, this section of code is within my html file. Should it be .php?

Comment: Yes change rename the file to .php rather than .html, all html will remain unchanged but the PHP code will be executed as PHP and not treated as static html

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know this was a thing, thank you so much, saved me many frustrating hours.

Comment: ha - wish I had posted on here when it happened to me - I had to go through those frustrating hours! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

`Mysqli_query` expect connection link as first parameter.

```
$results = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT title,url,details,file,submission_date FROM input");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, same result unfortunately.

Comment: @masteryupa: it can't be the same. What `mysqli_error()` to this query says?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "daemon", "xampp", "test");
        if (!$connect) {
            die(mysqli_error());
        }
        $results = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT title,url,details,file,submission_date FROM input");
        if (!$results) {
            mysqli_error($results);
            die();
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['title'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['url'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['details'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['submission_date'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This didn't appear to do anything, thank you though.

Comment: @masteryupa i have updated the answer try this and see what result you got, also vote up if it does help you that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick not so related improvement. You can avoid inserting most of the php opening and closing clauses:

```
 ...
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){ 
      echo "<td>".$row['title']."/td>";               
      echo "<td>".$row['url']"</td>";
      ...
  }
?>
```

Comment: I was told opening it only when needed reduced the server load somehow, is that wrong?

Comment: It is not wrong, but accessing the server also increases its load, so in a case like this it is better to access only one time. The load difference by having to echo and send the `<td>` code is almost null (because you're echoing and sending a simillar code anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<tr>` because **table must have atleast one row(`<tr>`) and one column(`<td>`)**

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "daemon", "xampp", "test");
            if (!$connect) {
                die(mysqli_error());
            }
            $results = mysqli_query("SELECT title,url,details,file,submission_date FROM input");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            ?>
                    <td><?php echo $row['title']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['url']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['details']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['file']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['submission_date']?></td>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: @masteryupa the `<tr>` is missing. Then tell what error you are getting?